# Log4j2 MarkerFilter contains an invalid element or attribute "onMismatch"

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

When trying to configure a marker filter in log4j2 using a property the following error appears:

> 2018-01-20 11:11:51,881 main ERROR MarkerFilter contains an invalid element or attribute "onMismatch"

Coresponding entry in the .properties file:

```
filter.muteHeartbeatEvent.type = MarkerFilter
filter.muteHeartbeatEvent.marker ="Heartbeat_Event"
filter.muteHeartbeatEvent.onMatch = DENY
filter.muteHeartbeatEvent.onMismatch = NEUTRAL
```

The [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter) clearly state that onMismatch is a valid attribute. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Could be a bug, check the Log4J2 JIRA issue tracker (accessible from the Log4J2 site).

Comment: @JimGarrison thank you. Are we talking about this page: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2 ? Currently I am not able to reach it.

Comment: I tried also, the server seems to be down right now; try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed in log4j 2 version 2.11.0. Check [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2202).

I get the same error on ***RegexFilter*** instead, so I'm guessing this issue is not limited to ***MarkerFilter***

```
ERROR RegexFilter contains an invalid element or attribute "onMismatch"
```